# Send a cell from table to a variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table like this:

```
table1(ID(int),total(int))
```

What I want to do is I want to send total value from table to a variable I made in C# using LINQ something like this:

```
int a;
a=table1.total();
```

Now I know this is wrong, pretty sure we have nothing of this sort in C# but I need something like that, because I wanna use this variable in another place. I have tried bringing it straight from table but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What exactly is a "table1"?  Is it some sort of collection?

Comment: no that's the name of my table you can imagine whatever you want really like i dunno "foods"

Comment: If its an `IEnumerable` then LINQ will work, otherwise not, so its kind of important what type it is. Also, do you want the total of all "total" variables in the table? Just one of them?

Comment: um..i kinda made that table in sql server and then using dataclass i brought it to c# im kinda new to linq can you explain how to do these?

Comment: You really need to start using some actual class names. `dataclass` does not exist in C#, and a full tutorial on ADO.NET and LINQ to SQL/Entities is a bit out of scope here. Please describe your database structure and what you are using to access it more completely (as an edit to your question)

Comment: Are you using linq to SQL to get table1?

Comment: founded the solution :

Comment: table1 b =          (from r in db.table1
                               where r.id == 1
                               select r).FirstOrDefault();
            int a= Convert.ToInt32(b.total);

Comment: sorry about how i wrote that code im new to site really sorry

Comment: That's definitely not LINQ. At any rate, you can self-answer your question. This one is still so unclear its probably not worth it though.

Answer (score -1):

ok so this is how i did it

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
table1 b = (from r in db.table1
             where row.id == 1
             select r).FirstOrDefault();
int a;
a=convert.toint32(b.total);
```

that pretty much did what i wanted now the variable a has the value of total from table1 and i can use it on other parts of program

thank you for taking the time to look at my question.